# Numbers above and below boxplots

Tags: python, pandas, boxplot

I need to have multiple boxplots in one figure grouped by hour of the day. qoi is the name of a column I need the data from out of a dataframe named qoi_val. For some information is shown above and below my boxplots and I have no clue why and how to remove it. Can anyone help me?

```
qoi_values = df_aq[df_aq['id']==126]
qoi_val=qoi_values[[qoi]]

qoi_boxplots = qoi_val.boxplot(column=qoi, by=qoi_val.index.hour, figsize=(30,8), ax=ax);
qoi_boxplots.set_title('Concentration C6H6 per hour');
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PBDvr.png, this is what it looks like

Comment: Try to create a new column with the hour and then use that column in `by='hour'`